# MvvmCross: Turn off MvxTrace timestamps (PrependWithTime)

Tags: mvvmcross

Looking for recommendations on how to override the default implementation of MvxTrace to disable the default behaviour of appending the time since application launch aka PrependWithTime:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/Platform/MvxTrace.cs#L152

```
    private static string PrependWithTime(string input)
    {
        var timeIntoApp = (DateTime.UtcNow - WhenTraceStartedUtc).TotalSeconds;
        return string.Format("{0,6:0.00} {1}", timeIntoApp, input);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I'd guess you can't easily override this behaviour.

If it's just text formatting you want to change, then you could remove the timestamps again afterwards in a custom `IMvxTrace` implementation injected during `Setup`.

However, if you wanted more customisation here, then you'd need to make some sort of change to Mvx - which you could do via a Feature Request or Pull Request in http://github.com/mvvmcross/mvvmcross/issues